# C#: Assign child class instance to interface implemented by abstract class

Tags: c#, oop

```
public interface IParser<T> where T: new()
{
    IList<T> Parse();
}
```

Above interface is implemented by following abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseParser<T>: IParser<T> where T : new()
{
   protected abstract string Sql { get;}
   public List<T> Parse()
   {
      // do parsing
      Console.WriteLine(Sql);
   }
}
```

Following are two concrete implementation of above abstract class

```
public class EMailParser: BaseParser<Email>
{
    protected override string Sql
    {
        get
        {
            return @"SELECT * FROM emails";
        }
    }
}

public class UrlParser : BaseParser<Url>
{
    protected override string Sql
    {
        get
        {
            return @"SELECT * From Url";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       if(args[1] == "url")
          Parser<Url>();
       else
          Parser<Email>();
    }
    static void Parse<T>()
    {
       // Create instance based on typof T and then assign to implementaion
       IParser<T> parser = typeof(T) == typeof(Url) ? new UrlParser(): new EmailParser();
       parser.Parse();
    }
}
```

I want to create instance of `EmailParser` or `UrlParser` base on generic type provided in `Program.Main` method and assign it to interface implemented by `BaseParser` (abstract class). How can I do this? I know i can solve this problem by modifying `Program.Parse<T>` as following

```
static void Parse<T>() where T: new()
{
    IParser<T> parser = typeof(T) == typeof(Url) ? new UrlParser() as BaseParser<T> : new EmailParser() as BaseParser<T>;
    parser.Parse();
}
```

However I want to know why I can't  assign child class instance to interface implemented by abstract class??

I can't understand why following line does not work

```
IParser<T> parser = typeof(T) == typeof(Url) ? new UrlParser(): new EmailParser();
```

and why this line work

```
IParser<T> parser = typeof(T) == typeof(Url) ? new UrlParser() as BaseParser<T> : new EmailParser() as BaseParser<T>;
```

**As per @nawfal answer this line also should not work because BaseParser and BaseParser are different types. Does there exists implicit case for IParser from BaseParser?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no implicit conversion between `UrlParser` and `EmailParser`. They both go back to `BaseParser<Url>` and `BaseParser<Email>` (or `IParser<Url>` and `IParser<Email>`) respectively, both of which are different types as far as compiler is concerned.

I would keep a dictionary to hold a map of type information and then use reflection. Something like (not tested):

```
static Dictionary<string, Type> typeInfos = new Dictionary<string, Type> 
{
    { "url", typeof(Url) },
    { "email", typeof(Email) },
    // and so on
};
```

And you do,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parse(args[1]);
    }

    static void Parse(string type)
    {
        var parserType = typeof(BaseParser<>)
            .Assembly // or whatever the assembly is
            .GetTypes()
            .First(t => t.BaseType?.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() == typeInfos[type]);
        dynamic parser = Activator.CreateInstance(parserType);
        parser.Parse();
    }
}
```

Use expression trees and/or cache things to make things faster.

**Update:** No, `BaseParser<T>` and `BaseParser<T>` are the exact same thing. `T` can only have one value at a time in your generic method. The real question is how can you cast `new UrlParser() as BaseParser<T>`. In a generic context it is possible to cast anything to anything using `as` C# rules are bit liberal there (I dont know the which part exactly in spec).

Comment: Thank you your explanation makes perfect sense :)

Comment: I got you point but I'm bit confused. Why does following line work

Comment: @Zeshan which line?

Comment: IParser<T> parser = typeof(T) == typeof(Url) ? new UrlParser() as BaseParser<T> : new EmailParser() as BaseParser<T>;    Why this line work? As per your answer in first paragraph this also should not work because BaseParser<Url> and BaseParser<Email>  are different types. For detail please see last two lines of code in my question.

Comment: I have edited my questions please start form line which read as follow "I can't understand why following line does not work".

Answer (score 4):

I believe the issue is that the compiler doesn't consider the type to which you are assigning the result of the 
    ?:
 conditional when parsing the conditional. Rather, the ?: is parsed in isolation, so the compiler can't figure out which type to use.

Edit: From section 7.14 of the C# 5.0 specification:

> The second and third operands, x and y, of the ?: operator control the
>   type of the conditional expression.  If x has type X and y has type Y
>   then:
>
> - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from X to Y, but not from Y to X, then Y is the type of the conditional expression.
> - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from Y to X, but
>     not from X to Y, then X is the type of the conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time
>     error occurs.

Comment: agree: OP problem is not related to generics, interface and abstract classes, but simply to the constraint required for the conditional operator. It would be the same writing `object obj = someCondition? new SomClass(): new SomeOtherClass();`

Comment: thanks for the response. Your answer convey same meaning as @nawfal but accepted answer convey same message as in much more clear language (first paragraph). Anyhow thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dynamic dispatch:

```
static IParser<Url> CreateParser(Url uri)
{
    return new UrlPaqrser<Url>();
}

static IParser<Email> CreateParser(Email mail)
{
    return new EmailPaqrser<Email>();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic t = new Url();
    var parser = CreateParser(t); // invokes CreateParser(Url uri)

    t = new Email();
    parser = CreateParser(t);  // invokes CreateParser(Email email)
}
```

Comment: I'm intrested in why that does not work. I'm well aware of provided solution. Anyhow thanks for the solution :)